# Instance variable naming conventions in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, coding-style, naming-conventions

This question is about variable naming style in objective c and cocoa.  I just want to stress that I'm not looking for a "right" answer, just good ideas.

I've read through Apple and Google's objective c style guides and I'm not really happy with either of them.  Apple's guide doesn't have any real style recommendations regarding instance variables vs local variables.  In fact, the Cocoa library itself seems perfectly happy having function parameters of the exact same name as instance variables.  That makes me cringe personally.

Googles guide specifies that instance variables should be indicated with a trailing underscore.  Alright, all well and good, but it suggests that we then synthesize every public property with @synthesize property = property_.  I don't know about anyone else, but I'll be damned if I'm going to do that for every instance variable in my project.  I think it's a wasteful and confusing solution.

I'm tempted to go with the myX (eg "myInstanceVariable") naming style for object properties, but I have rarely seen that style in objective c.

So yeah, what do you use?  Any style conventions out there I don't know about that you've found useful?  Do you think function parameters with the same name as instance variables is dangerous, especially in multiple developer environments?  Thanks guys and gals!

NOTE - As many people have pointed out, my terminology was off in the OP.  Apologies if the original wording hurt the clarity, but I think the point was still clear.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I tend to use non-prefixed **instance variable** names (note that "member variable" is a C++ism as it's suggestive of structures and classes being mainly interchangeable, which is not the case in Objective-C), and in cases where ambiguity arises, I use the Smalltalk convention of naming the **parameter** by its type with "a" or "an", e.g.:

```
- (void)setFoo:(SOFoo *)aFoo;
{
    foo = aFoo;
}
```

(of course, in modern ObjC you'd use a property for this.)

Using `theFoo` instead of `aFoo` is also somewhat common; see the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549962/instance-variable-method-argument-naming-in-objective-c).

The Google convention makes sense if you're really worried about conflicts.  If you use an [Xcode text macro](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/06/hidden-xcode-build-debug-and-template.html#textmacros) or tool like [Completion Dictionary](http://www.obdev.at/products/completion-dictionary/index.html) or [Accessorizer](http://www.kevincallahan.org/software/coding_styles.html) to generate your directives, it's pretty simple to adopt.

Note that the [Cocoa key-value coding guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Concepts/Compliant.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002172) pretty much assume either (a) you do not prefix/suffix your instance variable names, or (b) you implement (or synthesize) non-prefixed/suffixed accessors for them.  As someone else mentioned, do not use the _ prefix; it's reserved for Apple's use in their frameworks.

Comment: Good answer.  I agree that prefixing the parameter is cleaner than trying to shoehorn a convention into objective c instance variables.  The apple docs describe conventions for this in the case of common NSObject types, so extending it for your own types makes perfect sense.

I'm marking this as the answer because it best answered the main point of my question--avoiding ambiguous name spacing in class functions--and doesn't add any strange conventions or work-arounds.

Answer (score 6):

First: there are no "member variables" in Objective-C, there are "Instance Variables" or "ivars".

Google is NOT any kind of authority on Objective-C coding or Mac development.  Google Earth is a Qt app: 'nuff said.

I seem to remember seeing an official coding style guide from Apple for Objective-C, which I'm not finding at the moment.  This article is a pretty good summary, though:

http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000082.php

Found it! Here's Apple's official coding guidelines for Cocoa:

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html

Comment: Thanks for linking the apple guidelines.  I think the rest of this is off topic though.  Everyone seems keen to make use of their knowledge of c terminology taxonomy, but not answer the question at hand.  Also, Google may not have invented objective c, but they are certainly a valid source when it comes to coding conventions.  In this case, I don't think the Apple docs were explicitly clear about this and Google is.  I just happen to dislike their answer.

Answer (score 4):

In Cocoa, the style is to have pascalCased (or is that camelCased? I can never remember) names; and have the member variables be named the same as the accessor methods. (Such as `NSInteger anInteger`, `- anInteger` and `- setAnInteger:`).

It might not be the best style, but it's probably a good idea to get used to it if you are going to do any amount of work with Cocoa, as a number of mechanisms assume this particular kind of naming convention.

Comment: Sure, I'm aware of the getter/setter mandated conventions, and I wouldn't stray from camel case.  My question is more along the lines of notation used to signify the difference between an instance and member variable.

In fact, you can synthesize accessor methods with any name for any variable as in the google style, but that could be very confusing IMO.

Answer (score 1):

_foo is not bad habit. Or at least it is not anymore. See:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingIvarsAndTypes.html

Answer (score 0):

`m_variableName` is pretty common too for member variables.
Personally, most of the time, I just go with the same name for both variables and making the distinction between `this.varname` and `varname`.

Comment: Yeah I've seen m_X occasionally, but with the setter convention in objective c it seems messy.  setM_variableName?  I suppose if you stick to dot notation you avoid that though.

Comment: The "m_" prefix is a bad habit.  So is the single leading underscore, unless you're writing code for internal use at Apple.  Unfortunately, Apple's been letting a number of sample code projects hit the streets without proper cleanup.

Comment: Why is _foo a bad habit? Apple can't add ivars to Obj-C 1.0 code, so they can't break yours. And as I understand it, the compiler adjusts them in Obj-C 2.0 so that although Apple can break compilation of your code (easy to fix), already compiled programs will continue to work.