# Style: objective c and token concatenation

Tags: objective-c, coding-style, concatenation, token

This is a style question:

Because Apple reserves the "_" privatization for its keywords, I was thinking of something along the lines of the following:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

#define _(name) pvt_##name

@interface SFMeasureViewController : NSViewController {
    @private
    NSTextField *_(label);

}

@property (retain) IBOutlet NSTextField *label;

@end


@implementation SFMeasureViewController

@synthesize label = _(label);

@end
```

This is to help force the difference between `[self label]` and using `label` when it comes to retaining, and disposing of the variable properly.  Here, using the term "label" within the code returns an error, forcing the user to distinguish between a call to self.label or _(label).

Now `_(label)` contains 2 more characters (shift-characters at that) than _label does.  Is there any other good conventions out there?  `vLabel`?  Nothing is as quite as clear as `_label` but since its reserved, I don't want to use it.

Thoughts, critiques?  This is for a style guideline at work, for primarily C++ work using Objective-C++ when necessary.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Apple recommends not to use `_` as the first letter of anything, especially on method names. But as for instance variables, they themselves go against this principle in their sample codes. So I think `_...` is perfectly fine for that, without making the macro. I like the property names `var` vs. the backing instance variable `theVar`, too. More about this, see the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549962/instance-variable-method-argument-naming-in-objective-c) in SO.

In the new runtime (i.e. 64 bit on Mac, or iPhone OS, or iPhone simulator starting the ones coming with XCode 4) you don't even have to declare a backing instance variable explicitly; an ivar is created by the compiler when you `@synthesize` it, and you can't access that ivar directly. Thus, if you are OK with supporting only those platforms, that's the best approach.

Comment: You can access the synthesized iVars directly which, imho, makes using them ripe for misuse.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is not hard to distinguish label/self.label inside of module, so I doesn't see any problem in using the same name for property and field.

Comment: well, it is.  `label = nil;` != `self.label = nil;`  I'm trying to avoid n00b errors and sealing up as best I can memory leaks.

Comment: Yeah, I know that label = nil != self.label = nil. But I mean, that you, knowing that, can easily write correct code.

Comment: I can - it doesn't mean the n00bs on my team can, or that I always will after a late night playing ME2.